# Finding gems that rails application needs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I have a rails application which does not have a gemfile and was relying on global gems installed on the server. However those gems have been uninstalled from the server and I'm not sure which gems the application depends on to put in my gemfile to get it running again.

Is there any way to find out which gems I might need to get the application running again?

Comment: Do you have a gemfile.lock?  You might have to run the code and see what methods/classes are missing then google to see the library they're from and create a gemfile from scratch.

Comment: I'm afraid not, otherwise I would try there. The latter might be what I have to do.

Comment: You can check the ruby folder for installed gems, maybe there are some folders of uninstalled gems. Otherwise try to use a files recovery tool on the ruby gems folder and you will see what gems was deleted